# How to use \definecolor in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, color

I am preparing a beamer presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Sample Title}
\subtitle{Sample Subtitle}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \frame {
        \titlepage
    }
    \frame {
        \frametitle{Sample Page 1}
        \[\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - c}}{2a}\]
    }
    \frame{
        \frametitle{Sample Page 2}
        \framesubtitle{An Example of Lists}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \frame{
        \frametitle{Paragraph Content}
        This is a paragraph.
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is by default blue color "Sample Title" (in the above image). To change it I used

```
\definecolor{applegreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
```

But it does not make any changes. Please help me.

Comment: It is entirely clear, what you like to have. Changing color of  title? This can be done by accordingly change of color theme template.  For details see `beamer` documentation.

Comment: @Zarko I want to change the color of the title.

Comment: You still need to define color theme. They are described in section *17 Colors*, how to change colors are described in subsection *17.2 Changing the Colors Used for Different Elements of a Presentation*, page 188 of documentation for Beamer version 3.64.

Comment: As @Zarko mentioned, you may probably want to find out more about how to customize foreground and background colors. Take a look at **beamer** documentation which comes with TeXlive distribution for example. Open your terminal and run **texdoc beamer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of title is controlled by beamer color theme `title`, so you can use `\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=<color>}` to set it's (foreground) color.

Note the `subtitle` color theme inherits from `title` color theme, hence to remain the color of subtitle, you need to reset it.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Sample Title}
\subtitle{Sample Subtitle}

\definecolor{applegreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}

% change color for them `title`
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=applegreen}
% restore color for theme `subtitle`
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}
    \frame {
        \titlepage
    }
    \frame {
        \frametitle{Sample Page 1}
        \[\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - c}}{2a}\]
    }
    \frame{
        \frametitle{Sample Page 2}
        \framesubtitle{An Example of Lists}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \frame{
        \frametitle{Paragraph Content}
        This is a paragraph.
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. Can I restrict the frame title color as  t he color of main title (like here the apple green color)?

Comment: Change the corresponding beamer color theme, this time `frametitle`, similarly.